# How to set lock screen image through code?

Tags: android

Want to set a my app image on Lock screen of device when user is using the app and presses the lock button. And want to change it back to default when he quits the app.

Is This possible to do? Please suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome to create an [app widget that the user can elect to add to their lockscreen](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#lockscreen) on Android 4.2 and higher.